# BASIC: Probability of a box to contain n-keys

Tags: probability, multinomial-distribution

Consider the situation in which 4 boxes exist, as well as 4 keys. Each key is stored inside of a randomly chosen box. Now suppose we chose a box at random. What is the probability of the chosen box to contain a given amount of keys?

My thoughts were as follows. The odds of any given key to end up in any given box is P = 0.25. Similarly, the odds of containing precisely all keys is P = 0.25^4 = 0.0039.

Thus, I have considered the solution being

| # of keys | P |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1-cumsum = 0.667 |
| 1 | 0.25^1 = 0.25 |
| 2 | 0.25^2 = 0.0625 |
| 3 | 0.25^3 = 0.0156 |
| 4 | 0.25^4 = 0.0039 |

**But this appears wrong for a multitude of reasons.**

I have created a simple simulation of the problem using Excel (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q9EZZvNzgSrq0iF82DjOZfpNKO4qwcJSJLtkPmjJq2s/edit#gid=962295911), and the actual values (for any given box) are more close to

| # of keys | P |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.32 |
| 1 | 0.42 |
| 2 | 0.21 |
| 3 | 0.045 |
| 4 | 0.005 |

I am looking forward to seeing a correct theoretical analysis of the problem.

EDIT: *This problem has been solved. Please see frank's answer for the proper of way of computing the probability.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, without loss of generality, that we have chosen box 1.

**What is the probability for box 1 to contain zero keys?**
It is the probability to distribute all keys over only the boxes 2, 3, and 4: Each key has the probability of $\frac{3}{4}$ to end up in those last three boxes, and we have 4 keys, and their positioning is independent, so we get $(\frac{3}{4})^4$.

**What is the probability for box 1 to contain one key?**
There are four possibilities for box 1 (for each of the four keys) and each time the probability of the other three to be distributed over the last boxes is $(\frac{3}{4})^3$, i.e. we get: $4\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot(\frac{3}{4})^3 = (\frac{3}{4})^3$.

**What is the probability for box 1 to contain two keys?**
The probability that two keys end up in box 1 is $(\frac{1}{4})^2$. Then the probability of the other two to be in the last boxes is $(\frac{3}{4})^2$. And there are $\binom{4}{2}$ choices of two keys, so the total probability for this situation is $\binom{4}{2}(\frac{1}{4})^2(\frac{3}{4})^2$.

**What is the probability for box 1 to contain three keys?**
Similar arguments as the ones above lead to: $\binom{4}{3}(\frac{1}{4})^3\frac{3}{4}$.

**What is the probability for box 1 to contain four keys?**
Well, that is just $(\frac{1}{4})^4$.

I am afraid, your simulations are wrong. But this type of problem is notorious for being tricky in getting right. It is so easy to make a mistake. I hope my solution is correct. You also might want to check whether those probabilities add up to one...

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution is indeed correct. The answers you propose actually match the observations made from my simulations perfectly. How interesting.